# Why do objects go through dishwasher filters?

Tags: appliances, dishwasher, water-filtration

I have a brand new, top of the line dishwasher - a Bosch SHV89PW73N.

On a regular basis it errors out, failing to drain...

So we open up the mesh drain cover, take out the VERY fine mesh filter cylinder and we find actual objects down there.

Further, if you watch youtube videos on resolving dishwasher drain clogs, etc., you will see the same thing - pieces of debris like glass chips and macaroni chunks and so on that have gone THROUGH the filter complex.

This makes no sense.

The filter cover piece is a mesh of pin holes - not a very aggressive filter but certainly a LOT smaller than the objects I have removed from behind it.

Further, the fine mesh cylinder is a VERY fine filter.

It appears that actual objects can go over the lip of the filter cylinder and bypass both filters and just go right down the drain.

So my questions:

1. What is the point of these filters if actual objects and debris can just go right past them ?
2. Is it possible to patch this system such that EVERYTHING gets filtered and I don't have to keep opening up the filter panel and pulling out actual objects and debris from behind the "filters"  ?

Comment: The filters are probably to prevent the junk from going back into washing chamber of dishwasher, not to prevent the junk from leaving.

Comment: Just to be clear - the drain line on a dishwasher is almost comically small - perhaps 1/4 inch ?  So if you're not filtering debris you're going to clog that daily, with normal, expected, typical usage.  Like we are doing, for instance.  Why have  filter at all if debris can just go around it ?

Comment: Bits only get past if the filter has been refitted incorrectly. Check.

Comment: At least for organic stuff (like the macaroni) in my experience certain dishwasher detergents do a better job of softening them so they are torn apart more easily. Pre-soaking or similar cycles if available can help as well.

Comment: In the US I believe typical drain connections for dishwasher hose are 1 inch size. GE Appliances has the following statement about their machines: "All GE Appliances dishwashers manufactured since July 1989 include a drain hose with an inside diameter (i.d.) of 5/8 inch."